# sequence in latex not as expected

Tags: latex

I just started learning Latex and I have this code in which I first define a figure which is a photo and then I want to have items in my PDF file.
But the output file isn't so and it first shows the items and then the photo! even though I have `[!h]` statement too.

```latex
\documentclass[12pt]{report}

\begin{document}

\begin{figure}[!h] 
    \centering
    \includegraphics[width= 90mm]{./class.jpg}
    \caption{pic1}
\end{figure}

\begin{enumerate}
    \item first option with number
    \item second option with number
\end{enumerate}


\end{document}
```

Comment: If I remember correctly, `h!` is just a strong suggestion, but you cannot force LaTeX... what should it do if there is no room on the page? You may have better luck with this question on https://tex.stackexchange.com

Comment: What are the dimensions (in pixels) or the aspect ratio of the image? It is relevant to know how high is the image when the width is 90mm...then we go to the code.

Answer (score 0):

What I do is to use the package float and change !h for H

```
\documentclass[12pt]{report}
\usepackage{float}
\begin{document}

\begin{figure}[H] 
    \centering
    \includegraphics[width= 90mm]{./class.jpg}
    \caption{pic1}
\end{figure}

\begin{enumerate}
    \item first option with number
    \item second option with number
\end{enumerate}


\end{document}
```

This forces latex to place the image right in the position you put it.

Answer (score 0):

When I compile your code with `\usepackage{graphicx}`, and using a generic image, I first get the image, then the item list. Usually LaTeX will force the image onto the next empty page, if the image is too large (the width may fit, but possibly the height is off?). Maybe try playing with `\includegraphics[scale=0.8]`.